# Is there a way to loop through a matrix/array/df every 30 rows to return scipy.stats.describe

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, scipy

I want a loop that goes over every 30th row of a (1095, 10000) array, returns a `scipy.stats.describe(matrix[30])` and writes these results to a list

I have tried to do it manually and it works, I'm trying to optimise my code

```py
stats150 = scipy.stats.describe(matrix[150])
list_for_stats +=['150:', stats150]

stats180 = scipy.stats.describe(matrix[180])
list_for_stats += ['180:', stats180]

statsOut = open("myOutputStatsFile.txt", "w")
for line in list_for_stats:
    # write line to output file
    statsOut.write(str(line))
    statsOut.write("\n")
statsOut.close()
```

a for loop that is more intuitive than what I already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is a numpy array this loop goes through every 30th row of a (1095,10000) matrix of ones and stores the scipy.describe results along with the row number as a string in a list:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
matrix = np.ones(shape=(1095,10000))
list_for_stats=[]
for i in range(0,matrix.shape[0],30):
    list_for_stats +=[str(i)+':', scipy.stats.describe(matrix[i])]
```